# CORS error when running "pm2 start server --watch" but not "pm2 start server". No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, pm2

**edit:** Everything in this post is still accurate, but I've just noticed that the issue might be specifically when running `pm2 start server --watch` instead of `pm2 start server`.  This makes even less sense to me.  Updated title.

So I have a backend written in Node.js that works as a sort of REST API.  And I have a frontend in a separate project written in Vue.js which is only run locally (not hosted on a server) and is used to make requests and interface with my remotely hosted Node.js/Express API.

I'm making 2 requests on one of my Vue.js webpages to my Node backend using Axios.  In the backend, one of those requests routes to my online database, and one request routes to Twilio's API.  The issue I'm having is that when I SSH into my server and start my server with a simple `node server` command, the page loads fine and returns data for both requests.  However, when I instead have PM2 run the server with a `pm2 start server --watch` command, **only ONE of the two requests on the web page will return data**.  The other request will throw the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://*MYREMOTERESTAPI*' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Sometimes it is the Mongo request that returns the error while the Twilio returns data, and sometimes it is the Twilio request that returns the error while Mongo returns data.  **It is random** but favors Mongo I believe because it responds first.

Some code from the server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const cors = require('cors');

const fs = require('fs');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const winston = require('winston');
const path = require('path');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(cors());

mongoose.connect(MY SERVER INFO)
```

I have even added a .htaccess file to my server with the following code (to no effect):

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:8080"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Accept-Language, X-Access-Token, X-Client-Id, X-Secret-Id, X-GR-Token"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "X-Access-Token, X-Refresh-Token,X-Access-Token-Expire, X-Pagination-Current-Page, X-Pagination-Page-Count,X-Pagination-Per-Page, X-Pagination-Total-Count, X-Payload"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```

Comment: adding CORS responses to *your server* doesn't change the CORS policy of whatever `MYREMOTERESTAPI` ... that is obviously not the same server as `localhost:8080` - or is the htaccess stuff and the "code from my server" stuff what you've done on `MYREMOTERESTAPI`?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response in the cases where you get that CORS error message? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After realizing the issue was related specifically to pm2's "watch" flag (see edit at top of question) I was able to narrow down the issue.  Each time a request was made to my RESTful API, it updated the log file on the server.  Each time the log file was updated, pm2 would notice a file change and restart the server, never getting to send a response to the second request.

I fixed this by creating an ecosystem.config.js file for pm2 in the same directory on my server as my server/app js files, and utilizing the "ignore_watch" key to instruct pm2 to ignore changes to my logs folder.  Here are the contents of that file:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'my-pm2-process-name',
    script: 'server.js',

    // Options reference: https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/reference/ecosystem-file/

    instances: 1,
    watch: true,
    ignore_watch: ["logs"],
    autorestart: true,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
  }]
};
```

Comment: you saved my life. Exactly same issue – so confusing! Not nearly expecting a solution right here :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the config file structure from the other answer helped me, but I have also add some additional folders to ignore_watch, this work good for me:

```
ignore_watch: [".git/index.lock", "logs", "public", "node_modules", "[\\/\\\\]\\./","pids", ".git", ".idea"],
```

I had also some issues with amount of notify watchers, this [article](https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers#the-technical-details) helped me with this.

And in case of this issue repeat every ~60-90 sec and no files were triggered signal:

> pm2 has been killed by signal, dumping process list before exit...

Reinstalling pm2 helped me as well

```
pm2 kill 
sudo npm remove pm2 -g
    
sudo reboot
    
sudo npm install -g pm2
```